# Detect when orientation change has ended

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to detect when a user has finished changing the orientation of their mobile device, I'm using this event to detect when orientation changes, but I'd like to detect when orientation change has ended. Thanks

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From [orientationchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange) docs, *emphasis mine*

> The orientationchange event is fired when the orientation of the **device changed**.